# How do I get 'PCL' version of Nodatime?

Tags: android, xamarin, portable-class-library, nodatime

I'm trying to use Nodatime in Xamarin for Android. Apparently it is possible with the PCL build of Nodatime.

Problem is there is nowhere that explains how to get and use this 'PCL' build. Everyone just assumes we know what a PCL build is and where to get one!

Unfortunately I am not so enlightened.

Any direction to head me in would be greatly appreciated.

Le-roy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [NodaTime 1.2.0](http://nodatime.org/downloads/NodaTime-1.2.0.zip) zip contains a folder **Portable** with the PCL versions of the DLL's.  I assume that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes.  And also the regular nuget package contains both the standard and portable versions.

Comment: Thanks! I never found that .zip only the src and I tried NuGet but couldn't figure out how to get a 'PCL' version of the dll to reference from Xamarin. Well, I have it working now. Cheers.